# Prusa i3 Linux Mint Slic3r install problem

Tags: prusa-i3, slic3r, repetier, linux

New to this domain, I got my prusa i3 last week and finished assemblage. Repetier params in Linux Mint 18 are ok too.

I'm now trying to launch slic3r for the first time but I got this error launching config button in repetier :

> 23:40:37.298 :  Can't locate Boost/Geometry/Utils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Boost::Geometry::Utils module) (@INC contains: /home/mobidi/Téléchargements/RepetierHost/Slic3r/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at /home/mobidi/Téléchargements/RepetierHost/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r.pm line 32.
>
> 23:40:37.298 :  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/mobidi/Téléchargements/RepetierHost/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r.pm line 32.
>
> 23:40:37.298 :  Compilation failed in require at /home/mobidi/Téléchargements/RepetierHost/Slic3r/slic3r.pl line 13.
>
> 23:40:37.298 :  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/mobidi/Téléchargements/RepetierHost/Slic3r/slic3r.pl line 13.

Lines incriminated :

slic3r.pl line 13 :

use Slic3r;

Slic3r.pm line 32 :

Use Boost::Geometry::Utils 0.12;

I tried to reinstall with this tuto :
https://blog.lkiefer.org/index.php?article12/installer-slic3r-sous-ubuntu-16-04-et-linux-mint-18
But I got this error when dealing with the first command :

> Err:1 **********/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libpcre3 i386 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
>   404  Not Found
>
> Err:2 **********/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpcre3 amd64 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
>     404  Not Found
>
> Err:3 **********/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.23-0ubuntu7
>     404  Not Found [IP : 2001:67c:1562::19 80]

And a lot more almost indentical.

I don't know at all how to deal with this I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing at all, if somebody could guide me throught that I would be very thanksful.